# How to reverse a NumPy array in-place?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reverse

Is there any efficient way to reverse a NumPy **in-place**?

#### Note: I am **NOT** looking for a reversed *view*. I want the array to be truly reversed.

Comment: My guess is that copying the reversed view back on itself is the best you can do: `arr[:]=arr[::-1]`.  In other words, the data buffer has to be rewritten.  And even with that you might run to buffering problems.  `arr[:]=arr[::-1].copy()` might be safer.

Comment: @hpaulj: That's my guess too...

Comment: Why a reversed view is not good for you?

Comment: @Julien: `a = numpy.asarray([1, 2, 3]);` `print(numpy.add(a[::-1], 1, a))`

Comment: @hpaulj: Actually, I can't figure out if that ever runs into buffering problems or not. That's my only worry here. Do you know if it ever does? If it doesn't, then it's the answer I need...

Comment: @Mehrdad: [As of NumPy 1.13](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/release.html#ufunc-behavior-for-overlapping-inputs), the aliasing in `numpy.add(a[::-1], 1, a)` should no longer be an issue. (I believe this is achieved by creating a copy.)

Comment: On previous versions, the aliasing is an issue.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks a ton for letting me know! I believe the original code I had was more complex and not quite just that, but I'm not sure anymore... that's still great to know regardless.

Answer (score 0):

It's inelegant, but if in-place is the most important factor and runtime is not as important (as numpy slicing will far out-perform the iterative approach), you could always swap indices from the left and right ends of the array until the indices converge:

```
def reverse(arr):
    ln = arr.shape[0]
    lidx, ridx = 0, ln - 1

    while lidx < ridx:
        rtmp = arr[ridx]
        arr[ridx] = arr[lidx]
        arr[lidx] = rtmp
        lidx += 1
        ridx -= 1

    return arr
```

This will work for arrays of both odd and even lengths. Even:

```
>>> reverse(np.arange(4))
array([3, 2, 1, 0])
```

Odd:

```
>>> reverse(np.arange(5))
array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

And to prove it's in-place:

```
>>> y = np.arange(6)
>>> x = reverse(y)
>>> x is y
True
```

Answer (score -1):

As noted in the comments already this seems to work.

```
A = np.array([2,1,3])
B = A.copy()
B = B[...,::-1]
```

Comment: This doesn't reverse the array in place, which is explicitly what the OP requested. All it does is copy to a new array, make a reversed view of that array, and replace the copy with the reversed view.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. My posts should come with a student driver warning.  Can you expand on the practical difference between the two? i.e. in what circumstances would you want one and not the other?

Comment: Usually it's fine to make new copies and rebind the name. But sometimes you have a reference to an aliased object (most commonly seen when receiving arguments; your local variable bound to the parameter's name is typically bound to a name in the caller's scope too). In those cases, reassigning will not affect the caller; often you want that (no unexpected side-effects), sometimes you don't. In this case, the OP very clearly wanted to operate in-place, so clearly it was important that the original object be rewritten in place.